# Python and Eclipse: How to use interactive console after running a module, with the module variables and functions

Tags: python, eclipse, interactive

Let's consider 3 situations:

1) I write a pyhon module in Eclipse (pydev) and run it Ctrl-F11. The module runs and I don't have any control or access (AFAIK) to the module variables and functions.

2) I have defined a python interpreter as an external tool in Eclipse, so I can run it within Eclipse. It works fine, but it does not have tab completion.

3) I open my module with python IDLE (not eclipse) and press f5 (run). It runs on the IDLE opened window and when it finishes I have all the variables and functions form the module to play with.

So I have 2 questions:
a) how to enable, if possible, tab completion in python interpreter in Eclipse? If it's not possible, do I have any alternative to standard Python interpreter?

b) I would like to run step 1) and then be able to continue developing / testing with python interpreter, just like I do with IDLE, but all inside Eclipse. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run it as a debug operation in Eclipse, you should be able to set a breakpoint, and you can then examine variables, etc. But you can evaluate random python scripts via the watch functionality.

Comment: I know, but this does not have tab complete or ctrl-space complete and if I have an error during the evaluation I loose everything. I'm looking for something like idle that allows me to test quickly

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much has changed since the question was asked, but it's now possible to get code completion in the debug console (as of PyDev 1.6.0 according to http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debug_console.html, I'm on PyDev 2.8.1, Eclipse 4.3.0)

- Set a breakpoint in the code, on an executable statement (even just `print('')` or `True`). Double clicking on the grey vertical bar to the left of the code should do it.
- Run in debug mode with F11
- Eclipse may prompt to switch to the Debug Perspective; either way, the Console should be visible
- You should now be able to click in the Console pane and begin interactive debugging with code completion, even after a traceback. (Ctrl+Space works for me.)

Be aware that multi-line statements won't work unless they're split on `:` or `/`:

> Update in 1.6.0: commands are evaluated on each new line unless the line starts with ' ' or '/t' or ends with ':' or '/' (so, for entering multi-line statements, the input must be entered properly respecting those limitations).